# How to implement a YesNo box as a ViewController method?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertaction

I would like to add a method to my ViewController that shows a message with text as an alert with a Yes and a No button. The result should be of type Bool (Yes/No).

What I have tried is the following:

```
func YesNoBox(msg: String) -> Bool
{
    var retVal = false
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action_yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler:
                         { _ in NSLog("The \"Yes\" alert occured."); retVal = true })
    let action_no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler:
                         { _ in NSLog("The \"No\" alert occured."); retVal = false })
    alert.addAction(action_yes)
    alert.addAction(action_no)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    return retVal
}
```

However, the value of `retVal` is always `false`. If I was in C/C++, I guess I could resolve this issue with a pointer, but this is Swift (and I am pretty new to this).

Any idea anyone how I could get this working?

EDIT: The problem that I have is the following. On a ViewController I have a TextField. When I tap on the text field, the app should ask the user whether they want to paste the text from the clipboard. If yes, paste, otherwise give the TextField the focus (i.e. let the cursor blink in it). I tried to do this with 'textFieldShouldBeginEditing' and in this method I display the YesNoBox. The problem is that the TextField never gets the focus after the YesNoBox is closed. And when I use 'becomeFirstResponder()' after the Box call, the app freezes. I don't know what to do?

Comment: You return a value _synchronously_ while your handlers are operating _asynchronously_

Comment: Yes, I thought something like this must be the reason. But I cannot figure out how I can go around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a completion

```
func yesNoBox(msg: String,completion:@escaping(Bool) -> ())
{ 
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action_yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler:
                         { _   in
                          NSLog("The \"Yes\" alert occured."); 
                          completion(true)
                         })
    let action_no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler:
                         { _ in 
                           NSLog("The \"No\" alert occured."); 
                           completion(false)
                         })
    alert.addAction(action_yes)
    alert.addAction(action_no)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

---

call

```
yesNoBox(msg:"someMessage") { yes in
    if yes {
     // do yes action
    }
    else {
     // do no action
    }
}
```

---

**2 Callbacks:**

This function has 2 completions ( imagine we have a function that uploads an image and notifies the progress with a completion and another 1 to say done )

```
 func uploadImage(data: Data,progress:@escaping(Float) -> (),completion:@escaping(Bool) -> ()) {
    // implementation here
  }
```

To call

```
self.uploadImage(someData) { progress in
   print(progress)
 }) { done in
   print(done)
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. What does this `(val) in print(val)` mean or what does it do?

Comment: it's the value returned from the completion indicating whether the user clicked yes/no => true/false edited your next flow should begin from that `if else`

Comment: I don't understand this. I can replace `yes` by `go` or even `no` in the code and nothing changes. How does the compiler know that I mean that Yes was chosen?

Comment: Another question: Do you think that it is possible at all that the box is shown modally and the function returns true or false? My problem is also that the code after the function call is further processed while the user has not decided to choose from yes or no.

Comment: this is a placeholder for a variable name , actually you can place any variable name you like it doesn't matter , the important thing is that it represents `Bool ` var 2- during the presentation of the alert the callback will be called only after the user clicks yes/no it's like an infinite wait to user action

Comment: Sorry that I have so many questions. So, what if I have, for example, to completion handlers in the function definition? How does the compiler know which one I mean when I write `yes in`?

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll wait.

Comment: Hmm, the problem that I have is the following. On a ViewController I have a TextField. When I tap on the text field the app should ask the user whether they want to paste the text from the clipboard. If yes, paste, otherwise give the TextField the focus (i.e. let the cursor blink in it). I tried to do this with `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and in this method I display the YesNoBox. The problem is that the TextField never gets the focus. How can I make it get the focus after the YesNoBox is closed?

Comment: the textfield only get the focus when you click it given that you set the delegate ,  so since the alert is asynchronous you need to do that in the no part `else`

Comment: Actually, I don't quite understand what you want to tell me. So, assume I just want to do the following: when the user enters the TextField, show a simple alert with "Ok". After the user clicks "Ok" the TextField should have the focus. How do I do this?

Comment: the code you need to run when the focus happens according to your app logic put it inside `if yes` or `else` as you need , or do `self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()` to re-show the keyboard after the modal alert hides

Comment: When I call `becomeFirstResponder()` after the call to `self.present()`, my app freezes without showing any alert box. I think this is because the box does _not_ show in a complete modal way. The code further processes and `becomeFirstResponder()` results in another call of `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` and hence we end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: don't call it with the present , put inside `if` or `else` blocks

Comment: i mean don't call `becomeFirstResponder` along with `present` ,  you can even ignore `becomeFirstResponder` and decorate the textfield directly inside the else block as that means user clicks no

Comment: I don't have an else block in my minimal example anymore. Just an alert box with an OK button (as described above). So, there is no `if..else` anymore. Therefore, I don't get what you want to tell me. But never mind, I have asked this quesion as a new one since it is not directly related to this one here. So, I'll just check your answer. Thank you. That gave me a new insight into Swift (although still a little confusing ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with completion handlers.

```
func showAlertWithOptions(title: String, message: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action_yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { _ in
        completionHandler(true) 
    })

    let action_no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in
        completionHandler(false) 
    })

    alert.addAction(action_yes)
    alert.addAction(action_no)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now call the function and add any other functions or actions that you want to perform depending on the action selected.

```
showAlertWithOptions(title: "Any title", message: "Any message") { success in

    if success {
        NSLog("The \"Yes\" alert occured.")
    } else {
        NSLog("The \"No\" alert occured.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Christian. This is exactly the same solution as that from Sh_Khan. But the behavior I would really like to have is a modal yesno-box that waits for the user's input while the code processing is stopped. This I would like to encapsulate in this `YesNoBox()` function and I would like it to return a `Bool`. Do you think that this is actually possible?